# Add previous timestamp value to the next timestamp value of a particular column in HIVE query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a requirement where I receive data in 15mins interval. In my input table you can see that there is a column Total_sales where it should be aggregation of *previous timestamp value +  current_timestamp value*, instead of only current_timestamp value.

**HIVE query** should be in such a way that it gives me result as Output table.

I tried partition over by clause, but it is not working on timestamp.

Can you please help me.

Input table:

| timestamp_ | Dept_no | Product_no | Total_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-09-01 9:00:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:15:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:30:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:00:00 | Stock | Gel Pen | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:15:00 | Stock | Gel Pen | 1 |

Output Table:

| timestamp_ | Dept_no | Product_no | Total_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-09-01 9:00:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:15:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 2 , like(1+1) |
| 2019-09-01 9:30:00 | Sales | Black Ink | 3 , like(2+1) |
| 2019-09-01 9:00:00 | Stock | Gel Pen | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 9:15:00 | Stock | Gel Pen | 2 ,like(1+1) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytic sum() over():

```
with mytable as(
select '2019-09-01 9:00:00' timestamp_,'Sales' Dept_no,'Black Ink' Product_no,1 Total_Sales union all
select '2019-09-01 9:15:00','Sales','Black Ink',1 union all
select '2019-09-01 9:30:00','Sales','Black Ink',1 union all
select '2019-09-01 9:00:00','Stock','Gel Pen', 1 union all
select '2019-09-01 9:15:00','Stock','Gel Pen', 1
)

select timestamp_, Dept_no, Product_no,
       sum(Total_Sales) over(partition by Dept_no order by timestamp_ rows between unbounded preceding and current row) Total_Sales 
   from mytable;
```

Result:

```
timestamp_          dept_no product_no  total_sales     
2019-09-01 9:00:00  Sales   Black Ink   1   
2019-09-01 9:15:00  Sales   Black Ink   2   
2019-09-01 9:30:00  Sales   Black Ink   3   
2019-09-01 9:00:00  Stock   Gel Pen     1   
2019-09-01 9:15:00  Stock   Gel Pen     2
```